# commerce pricing attributes but disigned with commerce standard?

Tags: commerce

Is there an solution or plan to get the pricing flexibility from "Commerce Pricing Attributes" and option but designed with commerce standard?

Wrong prices are shown in the cart see her [Commerce Attribute price is not updating in cart](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117770/commerce-attribute-price-is-not-updating-in-cart) and https://www.drupal.org/node/2420303

joshmiller explained that the commerce pricing attributes module is not designed in commerce standard an therefore the pricing bug arises.

commerce pricing attributes are verry flexible if you need to have many of product variations/attributes. What could be a way to manage many product attributes similar to creation pricing options without the commerce need of creating 100 products, each for each option.

What can i do if a want to manage 30 products with 100 options each if i dont want to use the commerce pricing attributes with bugs?