# Adding priced options to products in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

For something that's pretty basic this seems overly complicated!  I'm working on updating a computer store from Ubercart to Drupal Commerce. Computers can be custom built so there are multiple options to choose. If I have to create a SKU for each variation I will go absolutely crazy!

So I've tried:

- bundling modules - but they doesn't allow you to choose options
- commerce pricing attributes - but it doesn't seem to work anymore "The "hunziker" approach to Drupal Commerce is not supported nor recommended by the creators of Drupal Commerce. Thus, any problems you might have with the modules is "by design" unfortunately." - [Commerce Attribute price is not updating in cart](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117770/commerce-attribute-price-is-not-updating-in-cart)
- Commerce Customizable Products - seems the most promising but after following the "pizza store" video multiple times even with a clean install - everything works A-OK till the rules. When I get to the part where I am adding in the rules, I can add in the "Entity has field" part properly, but when I add the loop, I don't have the option for just "commerce-line-item:field-foo". It ends the commerce-line-item:field-foo with a colon and wants you to pick more. no matter what combination I try I end up with a rule error about lists: "Error: The data type of the configured argument does not match the parameter's list requirement".

I'm absolutely going nuts with this!! It shouldn't be this hard... should it?

The process I'm following for Customizable products is as follows (adding an Antivirus choice to a custom computer content type):

1. Install [Customizable Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product)
2. Add a custom line item  Store > Configuration > Create New Line Item Type called “Custom Computers”
3. Create a Taxonomy, called "Computer Antivirus"
4. Add price field to taxonomy (with currency) called "Price" – Field Type “Price” > Currency CDN
5. Add a few taxonomy terms with prices
6. Add a Taxonomy term reference field "Computer Antivirus" to custom line item type, Store > Configuration > Line Item Types > Custom Computers

• Manage Fields

• Add new field “Antivirus” – Term Reference – Checkboxes

• Choose “Computer Antivirus” Taxonomy Vocabulary

• Include this field on Add to Cart Forms…

7. Set up products to use new line type. Configure the display of the add to cart form on the custom product type to use the custom line item type

•   Structure > Content Types

•   Choose Manage Display on the Content type you need to change

•   Edit the Product – Add to Cart form > Choose the Line item type “Custom Computer”

•   SAVE!!!

8. The custom options will now appear below the product
9. Change the price

•   Create a Pricing rule

•   Store > Configuration > Product Pricing Rules

•   Add new Rule named “Antivirus Rule”

•   Add a condition: Entity has field - Data Selector: commerce-line-item - Value: field_antivirus

•   **HERES WHERE THE PROBLEM IS  - Add a Loop:- Data Selector: commerce-line-item:field-antivirus - Current List Item: change name**

•   Add an action to the loop: - Commerce line item: Add an amount to the unit price - Amount Value: switch to data selection: pizza-topping: field-price:amount
 - Price Component Type: Fee - Value: Round the half up

I've been working with this about 4 weeks now with no solution. Can anyone shed some light on whats wrong?

Comment: at 6:26 of the video, in line items, did you set your term reference field to unlimited values?

Comment: so what's the problem with your rule? be more specific. You only listed the steps you did.

Comment: Hi No Ssssweat, in the points above my steps I mention the problem with the rule 
"When I get to the part where I am adding in the rules, I can add in the "Entity has field" part properly, but when I add the loop, I don't have the option for just "commerce-line-item:field-foo". It ends the commerce-line-item:field-foo with a colon and wants you to pick more. no matter what combination I try I end up with a rule error about lists: "Error: The data type of the configured argument does not match the parameter's list requirement".

Comment: Oh and no - I didn't set the term reference field to unlimited values because I only want them to pick one value from the list

Comment: Oooooooh Freaky!  So can I just skip the loop all together and just add the action?

Comment: yep, see my answer =)

Comment: You're the BEST!!!!  Marking it as the answer!!!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Mega kudos to No Sssweat for figuring this one out. I just gotta say, though, that creating custom product builders is hardly a basic use case. Even if it were basic from a data modeling standpoint (it's not), creating a simple UI for it would still be nigh impossible. I'm impressed you were able to get as far as you did and grateful to No Sssweat for pushing it over the finish line. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Oh and no - I didn't set the term reference field to unlimited values because I only want them to pick one value from the list

I believe that is the problem... either you make it unlimited; even though, you will use it once

OR leave it at 1, but don't use a loop, just add action (for Amount Value data selection use commerce-line-item:field-price:amount)